# azure jmespath query list with json

Tags: azure, azure-cli, jmespath

I have something like this from Azure nsg query

```json
    [
      {
        "access": "Deny",
        ...
        ...
        "sourceAddressPrefixes": [
          "x.x.x.x",
          "y.y.y.y"
        ],
        "sourceApplicationSecurityGroups": null,
        ...
        ..
      },
    ]
```

I'd like to query `sourceAddressPrefixes` from that list, both `x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y`, along with other attributes.

Those are what I've tried:

- `[?direction=='Inbound'].[name,destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes[*],priority]` this gives me the count of the list
- `[?direction=='Inbound'].[name,destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes[0:],priority]`  this still gives me the count
- `[?direction=='Inbound']. [name,destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes[],priority]` count still
- `[?direction=='Inbound'].[name,destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes[0],priority]`  this works, but only get one value.
- `--query "[?direction=='Inbound'].sourceAddressPrefixes[]" --out tsv` this works, but don't have other attributes.

I tried this in https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html and it works fine with just `[?direction=='Inbound'].[access,sourceAddressPrefixes]`, but not in the command line, even with quotes around the query.

I am running this on Ubuntu 18.4
python-jmespath verion 0.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding you made on the Azure CLI command. I see you want to filter the Inbound rules of the NSG and see some attributes. If you want to see all the attributes of the inbound rules:

```
az network nsg rule list -g groupName--nsg-name nsgName --query "[?direction=='Inbound']"
```

If you want to see some attributes of the inbound rules:

```
az network nsg rule list -g groupName--nsg-name nsgName --query "[?direction=='Inbound'].[name,destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes,priority]"
```

But for this, I suggest you use another format:

```
az network nsg rule list -g charles --nsg-name azurevmNSG --query "[?direction=='Inbound'].{name:name,destinationAddressPrefix:destinationAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefix:sourceAddressPrefix,sourceAddressPrefixes:sourceAddressPrefixes,priority:priority}"
```

This way will show you the attributes' names and values. Maybe it's more convenient to read if you add the parameter `-o table`.

Comment: I use "--out tsv" because it's easier to parse the output, but I didn't know this output format actually suppresses or change the output.  thanks.